# How do I say "the present one" in German?

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate a sentence ending in "in moments of crisis like the present one" and I am confused about how to say "the present one." I do not want to just say "this one" which would be "diese." Can I say "in Krisenzeiten wie die Gegenwärtige?"

I have looked at the pages on nominalization of adjectives and am still not quite sure if this is correct.

Comment: "In Krisenzeiten wie dieser..." (dative) would be fine. Or just "In Zeiten wie dieser..." or "In Krisen wie dieser...". Depends on what exactly you want to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Übersetzungstool https://www.deepl.com/translator schlägt, nicht schlecht, *in Krisenmomenten wie der jetzigen* vor, aber begeht einen Einzahl/Mehrzahlfehler, verbunden mit einem Geschlechtsfehler (dem jetzigen Moment). Zusammen mit https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/present kommt man leicht auf diese Kombinationen:

- in Krisenmomenten wie dem jetzigen/den jetzigen.
- in Krisenmomenten wie dem aktuellen/den aktuellen.
- in Krisenmomenten wie dem derzeitigen/den derzeitigen.
- in Krisenmomenten wie dem momentanen/den momentanen.

Einzahl-/Mehrzahlfehler deswegen, weil "in Krisenzeiten wie die Gegenwärtige?" kann entweder zu "in Krisenzeiten wie den gegenwärtigen" korrigiert werden, oder zu "in Krisenzeiten wie der gegenwärtigen". Dann passt aber besser die Einzahl auch vorne, also "in einer Krisenzeit wie der Gegenwärtigen", wie auch bei "in einem Krisenmoment wie dem jetzigen". Das muss man aber nicht zwingend übernehmen. 
Umgekehrt geht es aber meines Erachtens nicht: "In einem Krisenmoment wie den jetzigen ...", auch nicht mit *Zeit*.

Comment: Du vergleichst den *jetzigen Moment* und nicht *die jetzigen Momente* mit vergangenen. Deswegen muss es heißen *in Krisenmomenten wie dem jetzigen* (Einzahl). Schließlich sind jetzt ja nicht mehrere Momente sondern genau einer. Analog dazu wäre ja auch *bei Frauen wie meiner Tante Bertha* und nicht *bei Frauen wie meinen Tanten Bertha* richtig. Der englische Ausgangssatz verwendet hier auch den Singular.

Comment: Ja, natürlich, Flüchtigkeitsfehler beim Listenbau (siehe auch Fließtext). Hab 's korrigiert, danke.